# Which data structure in Java or Python should I use when I am trying to test requests to PHP-based server which expects array with String indexes?

Tags: php, arrays, testing, automation

I am trying to automate a back-end request to a PHP-based server. The server expects from me data written in a syntax of array with String indexes and encoded with Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

This is an example of request that is expected: `settings[hello]=word&settings[hello2]=world2`

 However, I have never seen anything like this in Python or Java. As far as I know there is no way to string indexes in these languages. What can be used instead then? Maybe dictionaries, tuples, list of dicts?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name URL parameters that way in any language. The reason is that this is part of the HTTP protocol, not the programming language.

You aren't dealing with any data structure at all, other than a string.  You're passing a string which the webserver will split into an array by splitting on `&` and then for each value in that array it will split that into another array or map by splitting on the `=`.  Then in each language you will have a method that retrieves those values by the name.

So, in Java:

```
 String hello = request.getParameter("settings[hello]");
```

In PHP (this is one way, maybe PHP has others):

```
 $hello = $_GET['settings[hello]'];
```